# Create a simple PNG WITHOUT using a library

Tags: functional-programming, png, filemaker

I need to be able to create a small PNG file - a horizontal bar with three colours of specifiable length on a transparent background -  WITHOUT using a library or external tool, i.e. no GD, ImageMagick etc.

I've gone through the PNG spec and figured out the basic block structure, and managed to work up a basic function for the heading, ending, but I was wondering if there was a simple compression format I could use to simplify the generation of the image data itself?

The environment is a FileMaker calculation - so pure functional code. I can manage it as a BMP already :-( but the solution requires a PNG  :-(  .

---

## Update

I have now got quite close to getting it to work - but I'm having trouble generating the actual IDAT data...

Say I want a 4 x 1 pixel image, with in 32bit, no compression, no filter, and no interlace - the IHDR is going to be:

```
49484452 // IHDR start
00000004 // Width
00000001 // Height
0806000000 // 32 bit color, alpha channel no compression, filter, or interlace

+ CRC32
```

I thought the IDAT should be something like:

```
00000010 // 16 bytes of pixel info
49444154 // IDAT start 
FF0000FF // pixel 1
00FF00FF // pixel 2
0000FFFF // pixel 3
FFFFFF00 // pixel 4

+ CRC32
```

but it doesn't want to play ball :-(

Am I misunderstanding the representation of uncompressed 32-bit pixel data?

In case any FileMaker users are wondering, the current FileMaker calc:

```
"89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d"  & // PNG header

//IHDR chunk
Let(
    [
        ihdr = "49484452" & // IHDR start
            "00000004" & // Width - 4 bytes
            "00000001" & // Height- 4 bytes
            "08" & // bit depth (per color), 1 byte (8 = 24/32 bit color)
            "06" & // color type, 1 byte (6 - red, green, blue and alpha)
            "00" & // compression method, 1 byte (0 = DEFLATE algo which allows no compression)
            "00" & // filter method, 1 byte (0 = no filter)
            "00" ; // interlace method, 1 byte (0 = no interlace)
        hcrc = BaseConvert ( ChecksumCRC32 ( HexDecode ( ihdr ) ) ; 10; 16 ) // CRC of IHDR chunk, 4 bytes
    ];
    ihdr & hcrc 
) &

// IDAT chunk(s)
Let(
    [
        idat = Upper( "00000010" & // byte length of IDAT chunk contents, 4 bytes
            "49444154" & // { 73, 68, 65, 84 } ("IDAT"), 4 bytes

            "FF0000FF" & // raw image data with DEFLATE algo wrapping, "byte length of IDAT chunk contents" bytes
            "00FF00FF" & // raw image data with DEFLATE algo wrapping, "byte length of IDAT chunk contents" bytes
            "0000FFFF" & // raw image data with DEFLATE algo wrapping, "byte length of IDAT chunk contents" bytes
            "FFFFFF00"  // raw image data with DEFLATE algo wrapping, "byte length of IDAT chunk contents" bytes
            ) ;
        dcrc = BaseConvert ( ChecksumCRC32 ( HexDecode ( Left( idat ; 31) ) ) ; 10 ; 16) // CRC of IDAT chunk, 4 bytes
    ];
    idat  & dcrc 
) &
// IEND chunk
"00000000"  & // byte length of IEND chunk, 4 bytes (value: 0)
"49454e44"  & // { 73, 69, 78, 68 } ("IEND"), 4 bytes
"ae426082"  // CRC of IEND chunk, 4 bytes (precomputed)
```

Comment: I guess you can change it from pmb to png by renaming the file without affecting the image